# How do you get "the raw bytes for the genesis transaction"?

Tags: transactions

This post

[How to retrieve the from and to wallet addresses of a transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50370/how-to-retrieve-the-from-and-to-wallet-addresses-of-a-transaction)

contains code by Nick ODell which refers to a file called 'genesis.bin' which contains "the raw bytes for the genesis transaction". I wonder if anyone knows how to retrieve that data?

Answer (score 1):

For regular transactions, if you have txindex=1 enabled on your node, you can call `getrawtransaction` to get the tx hex.

Interestingly, the genesis of the blockchain has a bug, and the genesis tx is not included in the UTXO set. Thus, you must get the genesis block, and take the transaction from that. You can do this using the `getblock` command, which outputs

```
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
```

In this, the genesis tx is:

```
01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff4d04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73ffffffff0100f2052a01000000434104678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5fac00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Using blockchain.info:

1) Go to genesis block:
https://blockchain.info/block-height/0

2) Click on block hash:
https://blockchain.info/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f

3) Copy hash of the first transaction, use rawtx api:
https://blockchain.info/rawtx/4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b?format=hex

Also see https://github.com/joric/pyblockchain